# How does the InsertChange event work?

Tags: autocmd

So this is in the help page (`:h autocmd-events`):

```
|InsertChange|      when typing <Insert> while in Insert or Replace mode
```

I don't really understand what it means with `when typing <Insert>`. So I tried it out by adding this into my `init.vim` file:

```
autocmd InsertChange <buffer> echo "yes"
```

then I opened a file and typed some random characters but `yes` isn't printed out. How is it suppose to work?

**EDIT**
I also looked into the more detailed description of `InsertChange`:

```
                            *InsertChange*
InsertChange            When typing <Insert> while in Insert or
                Replace mode.  The |v:insertmode| variable
                indicates the new mode.
                Be careful not to move the cursor or do
                anything else that the user does not expect.
```

But I still don't understand what `<Insert>` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InsertChange` is called when the *type* of insert mode changes; that is, if you change from insert to replace mode by pressing the Insert key.

With this:

```
autocmd InsertChange * :echom 'change to: ' . v:insertmode
```

Pressing `i<Insert><Insert>` should give you:

```
change to: r
change to: i
```

There is also a "visual replace" mode (which I just learned about!), and pressing `gR<Insert><Insert>`:

```
change to: i
change to: v
```

These are the only cases where this autocmd is triggered, in the `ins_insert()` function in `edit.c`

Comment: Should be mentioned, since OP since asks what `<Insert>` is, that it is referring to literally the insert key which may or may not exist on your keyboard.  Although `i` normally enters insert mode in vim, it's not the insert key.  Also when pressing `<insert>` twice from normal mode, we end up in replace mode, which is very different from what `i` does.